# Перевести время в число

Tags: python, время

Я это делаю так:

```
import time
a = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime())
h, m, s = a.split(":")
rez = round((int(h) + (int(m) / 60) + (int(s) / 60 / 60)), 2)
print(rez)
```

Может у вас есть способ как это правильно делается и без костылей. Спасибо

Comment: `time.localtime()` возвращает объект, из которого вы можете напрямую вытащить tm_hour, tm_min и tm_sec напрямую

Answer (score 1):

Как уже ответили в комментариях, все необходимые поля можно получить напрямую, без преобразований в строку и обратно.

Код будет выглядеть так:

```py
import time
time_now = time.localtime()
rez = round(time_now.tm_hour + time_now.tm_min / 60 + time_now.tm_sec / 3600, 2)
print(rez)
```